# R Model Tree M5P in R

Tags: r, model, tree, weka

I was wondering if the functionality given by Weka of building Model trees like M5P which has regression models in the leaves is possible in R. I know there is a way to handle it using the RWeka package. What was somehow strange to me is that the functionality does not exist in other R packages like rpart. The only way to get a "Model Tree" is using the Rweka package?
 Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Please check cubist and CORElearn packages.