# Is there a non-Java implementation of the M5P regression model of the RWeka library?

Tags: r, regression, rpart, rweka

I am looking for a function which creates the M5P regression model like the `M5P` function of the `RWeka` library (as the `M5P` function is based on Java code which has some drawbacks for me).
I tried the `cubist` function of the `cubist` library and the `rpart` function of the `rpart` library. These two models did not perform as good as the model from `RWeka` and also their out-of-sample predictions seem to be capped (increasing the input parameters of the model after a certain point does not increase the prediction value), whereas the model from `RWeka` can predict higher values with high input parameters (which I would like to be able to do).Thanks!

Comment: Please look at the answer to [R Model Tree M5P in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16153259/4752675)